# Python Pandas set_value will display the whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I just want to change a value in a specific cell in a dataframe, then I used set_value. However, every time I used set_value, it will list the whole dataframe one time. Since the dataframe has a large size (more than 10 millions row), the process will waste energy and time.
platform: Spyder(Python 2.7)

Grateful for advise!

Comment: Can you add sample of your dataframe and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
In [69]: df
Out[69]:
   a  b  c
0  8  6  2
1  9  9  6
2  1  7  9
3  9  0  6
4  0  6  7
5  9  3  4
6  4  6  5
7  8  3  4
8  0  8  9
9  7  2  8

In [70]: df.ix[5, 'a'] = 100

In [71]: df
Out[71]:
     a  b  c
0    8  6  2
1    9  9  6
2    1  7  9
3    9  0  6
4    0  6  7
5  100  3  4
6    4  6  5
7    8  3  4
8    0  8  9
9    7  2  8
```

instead of:

```
In [72]: df.set_value(9, 'a', 100)
Out[72]:
     a  b  c
0    8  6  2
1    9  9  6
2    1  7  9
3    9  0  6
4    0  6  7
5  100  3  4
6    4  6  5
7    8  3  4
8    0  8  9
9  100  2  8
```

you can also do it this way:

```
In [73]: df = df.set_value(9, 'a', 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

`set_value` is very fast. What is long in an interactive session is the  time to prepare the output.

```
In [130]: %timeit u.set_value(0,0,3)
10000 loops, best of 3: 41.9 µs per loop

In [131]: %timeit u.ix[0,0]=2
1000 loops, best of 3: 745 µs per loop
```

The second way prevent the display.

Comment: Thank you! The second way is what I want.